# Eclipse: Subclipse "Edit Conflicts"

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, subclipse

I have found that when using Subclipse to edit conflicts, all my syntax color settings are preserved except for the background color, which is reset to the standard white. Using my particular color scheme makes it almost impossible to read any of the text when stuck with a white background.

Is there anywhere I can change this default background color? There doesn't seem to be any way to do this from the preferences window, but perhaps there is a config file somewhere I could edit?

Any help would be very much appreciated (my eyes will thank you too)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you run into this eclipse bug: "[Compare editor background color doesn't obey settings](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=80213)". It seems to be fixed in 3.5 which will be released soon.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in eclipse. Have you tried filing a bug report?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this is not fixed in 3.5.1.

I'm on 
Version: 3.5.1.R35x_v20090910-9gEeG1_FthkNDSP2odXdThaOu9GFDPn83DGB7
Build id: M20090917-0800

and the background color of the Diff Editor is still white no matter what.

The bug report mentioned above says milestone 3 is the target, so thats probably why its still a bug for me. The question is- does the target release of 3.5 milestone 3 mean the fix was incorporated to eclipse 3.6?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the latest eclipse (indigo) and I have a similar problem.  The compare editor is really dark colored: The background is black, the text is not colored like it would be in a normal eclipse editor.  It is impossible to read with these colors.   This is a fresh install of eclipse (I hoped that a fresh install would fixed the problem - I was using helios with the same problem.  I am using the same workspace however): all I have right now it PDT, Subclipse, and a few web tools (CSS XHTML...)