# Subclipse diff change black background

Tags: eclipse, svn, user-interface, colors, subclipse

I'm running Subclipse on several systems.  Mac and Linux seem fine, but on Windows the diff view on the commit panel has a black background which makes it impossible to read.  Tried poking around the Preferences > Team > SVN and Preferences > Editors but can't seem to find where this is set.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be useful : [Eclipse: Subclipse "Edit Conflicts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451584/eclipse-subclipse-edit-conflicts) ?

Which version of eclipse are you using ?

It seems like this could be a bug with versions of Eclipse before 3.5. If that applies to you then take a look at **[this](http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=928)** subclipse bug and upgrade to a newer version if that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

The compare tool and UI is part of the Eclipse platform.  To the degree it can be customized it would likely be in the Eclipse preferences under General > Appearance and/or Compare.  It is not something Subclipse controls or tries to define.  I have never seen a black background in a standard Eclipse distribution text editor.  Perhaps it picks up defaults from the OS?  Do you use black backgrounds anywhere else?